# Select data from dataset or datatable where the data not present in another database using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datatable, dataset, sqldataadapter

I want to insert data from remote MSSQL database to local MSSQL database. But there should be one condition, only those data will be selected for insert which is not present in my local database.table. I can fill dataset or datatable from remote data and update the local data table. But getting error after first successful insertion. Error is Duplicate data insertion related. So is there any way by which I can select only those datas from filled dataset or datatable which are not present in my local database.table? My CODE is below.

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.DataTable
Imports System.Data.DataSet
Class MainWindow
Dim dsl As New DataSet()
Dim dal As New SqlDataAdapter()
Dim conr As String = ("Data Source=MOONLOADER\MSSQLSERVER2005;Initial Catalog=SSBYM;User ID=sa;Password=sasa;")
Dim cnr As New SqlConnection(conr)
Dim conl As String = ("Data Source=MOONLOADER\MSSQLSERVER2005;Initial Catalog=SSBY;User ID=sa;Password=sasa;")
Dim cnl As New SqlConnection(conl)
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Try
        'UPDATING URNLIST
        dal.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("select URN from TxnEnrollment", cnr)
        dal.AcceptChangesDuringFill = False
        dal.Fill(dsl, "URNLIST")
        Dim dar As New SqlDataAdapter("select * from URNLIST", cnl)
        Dim U As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(dar)
        dar.Update(dsl, "URNLIST")
        'UPLOADING ENROLLMENT DATA
        dal.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("select * from TxnEnrollment where Personalized='1' and URN not in (SELECT URN FROM URNLIST)", cnl)
        dal.AcceptChangesDuringFill = False
        dal.Fill(dsl, "TxnEnrollment")
        Dim dar0 As New SqlDataAdapter("select * from TxnEnrollment where Personalized='0'", cnr)
        Dim U0 As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(dar0)
        dar0.Update(dsl, "TxnEnrollment")
        'UPLOADING DEPENDENT DATA
        dal.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("select * from TxnDependents where Enrolled='1' and URN not in (SELECT URN FROM URNLIST)", cnl)
        dal.AcceptChangesDuringFill = False
        dal.Fill(dsl, "TxnDependents")
        Dim dar1 As New SqlDataAdapter("select * from TxnDependents where Enrolled='0'", cnr)
        Dim U1 As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(dar1)
        dar1.Update(dsl, "TxnDependents")
        cnl.Close()
        cnr.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("Uploaded Successfully")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: @DIPANKAR If both tables have a primary key then then your local table wont insert the incoming row, I am guessing this is what your exception is concerning.

Comment: Yes you are wright. Both table have primary key, Because I want unique data in each row. I don't want to insert same data twitch.

Comment: You should be able to safely ignore the exception. Are you seeing results of duplicate data?

Comment: No, not that. It is something like this "YOU HAVE 1,2 AND 3. I HAVE 1,2,3 AND 4. SO I WILL GIVE YOU ONLY 4. BECAUSE YOU DON'T HAVE ONLY 4"

Comment: you can generate a a string for an IN operator. Get all the pk values from local and update WHERE not IN(your string of vals)

Comment: Actually I'm too much confused. Can you assist me? I just need to insert URN from remote database while URN not present in local database. Need to change only UPDATING URNLIST part. URN data type is varchar(17). How can I convert URN to string?